# how to use Backbone Collection to fetch this JSON result?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I have the following JSON reply

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "Product":{
            "id":"1",
            "short_name":"Infra - 2200 CAS Sma SIMO onl [DAS.1.1]",
            "serial_number":"DAS.1.1",
            "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "full_name_type":"2200",
            "full_name_cas_stk":"CAS",
            "full_name_size":"Small",
            "full_name_simo_mimo":"SIMO only",
            "full_name_product_code":"(2961-737)",
            "uom":"lot",
            "material":"Infra"
         },
         "Price":[
            {
               "id":"1",
               "product_id":"1",
               "source_file":"LTE Test File.xls",
               "for_financial_year":"FY12_13",
               "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "gross_unit":"50.00",
               "gross_total_value":"0.00",
               "gross_total_formula":"=K12*J12",
               "incentive_value":"5",
               "incentive_formula":"5",
               "net_price_unit":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_value":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_formula":"=N12*J12"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Product":{
            "id":"2",
            "short_name":"Infra - 2200 CAS Sma SIMO to  [DAS.1.2]",
            "serial_number":"DAS.1.2",
            "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "full_name_type":"2200",
            "full_name_cas_stk":"CAS",
            "full_name_size":"Small",
            "full_name_simo_mimo":"SIMO to MIMO Retrofit",
            "full_name_product_code":"(2961-737)",
            "uom":"lot",
            "material":"Infra"
         },
         "Price":[
            {
               "id":"2",
               "product_id":"2",
               "source_file":"LTE Test File.xls",
               "for_financial_year":"FY12_13",
               "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "gross_unit":"11.00",
               "gross_total_value":"0.00",
               "gross_total_formula":"=K13*J13",
               "incentive_value":"24",
               "incentive_formula":"24",
               "net_price_unit":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_value":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_formula":"=N13*J13"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "Product":{
            "id":"3",
            "short_name":"Infra - 2200 CAS Sma Full MIM [DAS.1.3]",
            "serial_number":"DAS.1.3",
            "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
            "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
            "full_name_type":"2200",
            "full_name_cas_stk":"CAS",
            "full_name_size":"Small",
            "full_name_simo_mimo":"Full MIMO",
            "full_name_product_code":"(2961-737)",
            "uom":"lot",
            "material":"Infra"
         },
         "Price":[
            {
               "id":"3",
               "product_id":"3",
               "source_file":"LTE Test File.xls",
               "for_financial_year":"FY12_13",
               "created_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "modified_by":"Wesley Jace Tan",
               "created":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "modified":"2013-02-11 07:58:20",
               "gross_unit":"12.00",
               "gross_total_value":"0.00",
               "gross_total_formula":"=K14*J14",
               "incentive_value":"5",
               "incentive_formula":"5",
               "net_price_unit":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_value":"0.00",
               "net_price_total_formula":"=N14*J14"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The url to retrieve the above data is /products/index.json

The url to retrieve page 2 of products data is /products/index.json/page:2

I have written the following as the Collection

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        window.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: $("body")
        });
        var appview = new AppView;

        var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Product, 
            url: '/products/index.json'
        });

        Products.fetch();
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I think I have written the `Products` Collection wrongly.

Please advise.

**UPDATE**

This is my new code http://jsfiddle.net/Cw6PT/

This is the error message I now have: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return c.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'fetch'

Comment: first, your JSON represantation of Product is unfortunate. Price should be a descendant to Product not a sibling in this case. And then you should use .parse method to tell Collection to take items from results array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Products` is a `Collection` class, not a `Collection` object. Changing your code to

```
new Products().fetch()
```

or

```
var Products = new (Backbone.Collection.extend(...))
```

should work. Besides, if you want to customize how to parse the JSON reply, you could override [collection.parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse).

Comment: THank you. I have a follow up question based on your reply. Basically it has to do with parsing the JSON reply into 2 models instead of 1. Please advise. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14847498/80353

Comment: I understood your answer conceptually. BUt it did not work for me hence I did not accept as answer. This is my new code and my new error message is Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return c.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'fetch'

Comment: Just notice you've taken my second suggestion. Sorry I forgot parenthese around `Backbone.Collection.extend(...)`(already fixed in the answer). Now it should work.

Comment: I have accepted your code and added changes to make it easier to see. Thank you!!

Comment: it's my pleasure to have helped you.